# Django-CMS 2.3 site missing static content

Tags: django-cms

After installing, with some trouble, django-cms to run in a virtualenv. I may load the index page as well as the admin pages. However, on the index page, I see the following text at the bottom

> If you don't see the django CMS logo at the end of this line make sure
>   you linked the static/cms folder to your static files: here should be
>   a logo

The logo is missing. Loading the admin page loads plain black and white HTML undecorated with CSS and other static components of the page.

My access.log shows the following when loading www.mysite.com

```
 ..."GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4214 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"
 ..."GET /static/cms/images/pony.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 526 "http://www.mysite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"
 ..."GET /static/cms/images/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 527 "http://www.mysite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"
```

Similar errors are seen when loading the access log. Not that no "static" directory was created upon generation of the site.

My question is this : Do I simply copy the contents of /usr/local/pythonenv/django_cms_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/static/ into the STATIC_ROOT defined in settings.py ?

My follow up would be, why doesn't this get done automatically ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried running the `collectstatic` management command?

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

A quick glance at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) might help as well :-)

Comment: Sorry, my "glance" comment wasn't meant to be derogatory. I just wanted to point you into the right direction so you can read up on the whole staticfiles app.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. It is sometimes easy to read subtext wrongly online. Again, your advice is right on, and It gives me a new way think about researching the use of Django's utilities.

Comment: Nearly 5 year later I'm in the same situation as @OYRM and I had to look  into Internet because this is not a command you find clearly on the documentation. Thanks Benjamin :)